# Git Large File Storage (LFS) for Docker Images?

Tags: docker-registry, dockerhub, git-lfs

Is it possible to use Git Large File Storage (LFS) to store Docker Images and avoid the use of Docker Registry? Why / why not?

Also, if it is possible, what are the drawbacks of this approach that one should be aware of?

Comment: You cannot remove old images

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you technically can remove old commits from git, if you need to. But why would you want to remove the old images? They'd go side by side with the code that produced them. That's why I'm asking - what would be a drawback. Okay, if we consider the difficulty to remove an old image a drawback - than let's count it as one of them. Any more ideas? -- Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure it's possible to do, but it's not a good idea.  There are a couple of reasons:

- You will store every Docker image that you've ever used forever, even if you never care about them.  Since a single image can easily run hundreds of megabytes, you can find yourself storing terabytes of data you'll never use again pretty easily.
- Using Git LFS for this means that you can't use the standard Docker tooling to check out an image.  That makes it much more laborious to work with and prevents you from taking advantage of lots of other tools that work with the Docker ecosystem.
- In general, Git repositories, with or without Git LFS, are not good stores for binary artifacts and are not a substitute for an artifact server.  Neither the developers of Git nor those of Git LFS take these use cases into account and neither will generally add features or functionality supporting them.